# Asp.Net while using tabbing in bootstrap can not retain focus on selected tab on post back

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, setfocus, tabbing

I'm using a bootstrap template for my project while using tabbing when page postback from 2nd tab again first tab shows on. I tried different things but wont work please help.

```
<div id="validationWizard" class="basic-wizard">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li><a href="#vtab1" data-toggle="tab"><span>1 :</span> Basic Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vtab2" data-toggle="tab"><span>2:</span> Family Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vtab3" data-toggle="tab"><span>3:</span> Previous School</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vtab4" data-toggle="tab"><span>4:</span> Document Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vtab5" data-toggle="tab"><span>5:</span> Registration Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vtab5" data-toggle="tab"><span>5:</span> Save Details</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#validationWizard a[href="#vtab2"]').tab('show')             
 I have tried this 1 in document.ready function so it is loading tab 2 but same line if im calling in a btn.click function its not working

Answer (score 0):

You will need to maintain the state of the tabs explicitly by saving the current tab index in hidden field and setting current tab after page renders using javascript/jquery. As you are applying tabs style on client-side, server doesn't know about the state of the current active tab. If you use asp.net ajax control toolkit - tab control then ASP.NET automatically maintain the state of the tab.

Comment: vaibhav i tried that but still failed. can u give me proper code to do that